# AND using XOR and OR?

Tags: computer-science, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Is there a way to make an AND using only XOR and OR.  I know that a XOR b = ab'+ba' but I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche No I didn't think of it myself, my cousin asked me to help him out. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:  (A XOR B) XOR (A OR B)

Comment: $
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
$Here is a bit more detail about *why* this works, writing $\;\not\equiv\;$ for XOR and noting that this operator is associative, just like $\;\equiv\;$:

$$\calc
P \land Q
\calcop\equiv{logic: what Dijkstra et al. call the 'golden rule'}
P \lor Q \;\equiv\; P \;\equiv\; Q
\calcop\equiv{logic: double negation}
P \lor Q \;\not\equiv\; P \;\not\equiv\; Q
\endcalc$$